# Looping through pandas dataframe to generate a date range

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, date-range

I have a dataframe as shown here:
[image]

For every range '**From**' to '**To**', I want to create a date_range. So I am looping over the dataframe. For every row, there is a DatetimeIndex generated.

I tried to convert this to a dataframe and append it to an empty dataframe, so I have the overall range. But the final dataframe (day_wise) ends up being empty! So not sure where the problem lies.

```
day_wise = pd.DataFrame(columns=['day'])
for index, row in elec_ds.iterrows():
  for_day = pd.date_range(start=row['From'], end=row['To'], freq='D')
  for_day = pd.DataFrame(for_day)
  day_wise.append(for_day)
```

Comment: The DataFrame append method differs from Python's list append method.  For a DataFrame, you have to assign to a variable.  For example, `day_wise = day_wise.append(for_day)`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `for` loop entirely. Assuming you are on pandas v0.25 or later so you can use `explode`:

```
day_wise = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['From'], row['To']), axis=1) \
                .explode() \
                .to_frame('Day')
```

Result:

```
    Day
0   2018-10-23
0   2018-10-24
0   2018-10-25
0   2018-10-26
0   2018-10-27
```

Explanation:

- `apply(lambda ..., axis=1)` makes a date range from the `From` and `To` columns of each row
- `explode` splits the range into individual days
- `to_frame` convert the Series into a DataFrame